# using dygraph library in r to plot dual axis

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot two series at different scales on same plot with dygraph lib in r.

```
dygraph(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10),y2=runif(10)*100)) %>%
  dyAxis("y", valueRange = c(0, 1.5)) %>%
  dyAxis(runif(10)*100,name="y2", valueRange = c(0, 100)) %>%
  dyEvent(2, label = "test") %>%
  dyAnnotation(5, text = "A")
```

however, The plot does not fit the data with larger scale, I cannot figure out how to align the two axises. I suspect the option independentTicks in dyAxis() function does the trick but I cannot find how to use it in the documentation. Please help out with this. Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be:
We pass the **named vector** of the column with higher values to `dySeries` function:
See here https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-axis-options.html

```
library(dygraphs)
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10),y2=runif(10)*100)

y2 <- df %>% 
  pull(y2)
names(y2) <- df$x

dygraph(df) %>%
  dySeries("y2", axis = 'y2')
```

[image]